# How can I plot from a plot handler?

Tags: matlab

I have the handler of the plot, or handle of the figure
Example:

```
h = plot([1:0.2:10])
xx=get(h)
xx = 

           DisplayName: ''
            Annotation: [1x1 handle]
                 Color: [0 0 1]
             LineStyle: '-'
             LineWidth: 0.5000
                Marker: 'none'
            MarkerSize: 6
       MarkerEdgeColor: 'auto'
       MarkerFaceColor: 'none'
                 XData: [1x46 double]
                 YData: [1x46 double]
                 ZData: [1x0 double]
          BeingDeleted: 'off'
         ButtonDownFcn: []
              Children: [0x1 double]
              Clipping: 'on'
             CreateFcn: []
             DeleteFcn: []
            BusyAction: 'queue'
      HandleVisibility: 'on'
               HitTest: 'on'
         Interruptible: 'on'
              Selected: 'off'
    SelectionHighlight: 'on'
                   Tag: ''
                  Type: 'line'
         UIContextMenu: []
              UserData: []
               Visible: 'on'
                Parent: 173.0107
             XDataMode: 'auto'
           XDataSource: ''
           YDataSource: ''
           ZDataSource: ''
```

This handler contains all the plot information, how can I plot out again? This is a simple example with `plot` but it is supposed to work with `slice` as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to reproduce a plot using the struct `xx`. 
The answer ccook provided is on the right track, but here's a shorter way to achieve what you want:

```
figure
h2 = plot(0);
ro_props = [fieldnames(rmfield(xx, fieldnames(set(h2)))); 'Parent'];
xx = rmfield(xx, ro_props);
set(h2, xx)
```

The last `set` command uses struct `xx` to set all the values and reproduce your plot. Note that the read-only properties `ro_props` are removed from `xx` before calling `set`.

*EDIT: modified answer to automatically detect read-only properties according to [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13803861/1336150).*

Comment: Very nice - the last step would be finding the read only property names dynamically.

Comment: @ccook I would love to know how to do :-)

Comment: as would I, seems only appropriate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13801873/get-a-list-of-read-only-property-names-for-a-plot

Answer (score 5):

You can use copyobj

```
h = plot([1:0.2:10])
xx=get(h)
figure
copyobj(h,gca)
```

This duplicates the plot onto a new figure

See:  http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/copyobj.html

UPDATE

I don't think you can create directly from the structure xx, trying to do so:

```
h = plot([1:0.2:10])
xx=get(h)

h2 = plot(0,0)
set(h2,xx)
```

Throws an error

```
Error using graph2d.lineseries/set
Changing the 'Annotation' property of line is not allowed.
```

You would need to set some of the property values manually like so:

```
h = plot([1:0.2:10])
xx=get(h)


figure
h2 = plot(0.0)

names = fieldnames(xx);

fieldCount = size(names,1);

protectedNames = {'DisplayName' 'Annotation' 'BeingDeleted' 'Type' 'Parent'}

for i = 1:fieldCount
    name = names{i};
    if ( ismember(protectedNames, name) == false  )


        set(h2, name, getfield(xx,name))

    end
end

yy=get(h2)
```

Comment: How does this incorporate struct `xx`?

Comment: Ahh - my mistake (was thinking that was to display the info)

Comment: Much better I think, but it looks a little clumsy. There is no need in the `loop`, you can feed the struct directly into `set`.

Comment: You can't set all of the properties as some are read only - the loop is to show that selection.  You could do a index of on the protectedNames to remove them from names and save some lines by assigning the modified array.  I agree its bulky, for production I would move to a function and handle the read only aspect dynamically.

Comment: ccook Of course. You have to remove those fields with `rmfield`. Have a look at my answer.

Comment: @EitanT like that... I would clean up - but then its the same answer now.  Much nicer (was not aware of rmfield)  :)

Comment: It's the same idea, but a different implementation. You being the first to answer, I let you take a shot at it... but seeing that you resorted to a loop I decided to offer my alternative solution. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a simpler way, but you have the x,y values inside XData and YData.

Do:

```
figure
plot(get(h,'XData'),get(h,'YData'))
```

Comment: I believe this is not what the OP wants. This extracts the data from handle `h`, not from the struct `xx`. Also, this doesn't handle other properties such as line style, color, etc...