# Get a list of read only property names for a plot

Tags: matlab

If you want to copy a plot through the property structure you need to filter out the read only properties (such as Annotation, BeingDeleted, Parent, Type).  Is there a way to get a list of read only properties for the object?

The question arose from a related question

[How can I plot from a plot handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800043/how-can-i-plot-from-a-plot-handler/13801566)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I started to muck around with the previous question, trying to dynamically find out which fields were settable.

I didn't quite get it to work but I could get hold of (most of) the read only properties by using the difference between the return values of `set(h)` and `get(h)`.

The only property that doesn't show up here is the `Parent`-property which is settable but is not supposed to be changed in the previous question.

Here is how I got the non-settable properties:

```
h = plot(1:0.2:10);
xx=get(h)

close all
h2 = plot(0);
settableHandles = set(h2);
settableNames = fieldnames(settableHandles);
allHandles = get(h2);
allNames = fieldnames(allHandles);

nonSettableHandles = rmfield(allHandles,settableNames);
nonSettableNames = fieldnames(nonSettableHandles)
```

This produces a cell of `nonSettableNames`:

```
nonSettableNames = 

    'Annotation'
    'BeingDeleted'
    'Type'
```

Comment: I guess you can reduce everything to a one liner: `fieldnames(rmfield(get(h), fieldnames(set(h))))`. Pretty clever, +1.

Comment: @EitanT +1 for the one liner!

Comment: +1 - I never even noticed that I can get a return value from `set`!

Answer (score 2):

why not use something like

```
try
    %// [set property]

catch ME
    if ~isempty( regexp(ME.error, 'read only') )
        continue;

    else
        %// [handle other error]

    end

end
```

Comment: Nice - are the try/catch blocks expensive in Matlab?

Comment: copyobj has been discussed, but it uses the plot handler directly, not the plot properties :)

Comment: Well, they *can* be, especially when used in a loop; the `ME` part is a call to the `MException` class, which is non-builtin, so any loop will not be accelerated by JIT. But this will be non-applicable when you're using external calls anyway. Besides -- I think it's not likely that your `try...catch` will really be very expensive compared to all the rest.

Comment: @ccook: compared to how expensive plotting is, `try/catch` won't be felt at all.

Comment: Perspective does help :) TY