# Octave graphs: How to display possible property-values using get/set?

Tags: matlab, gnuplot, octave

When i have plotted a graph in octave, i usually want to play around with it for some time in order to make it look shiny and all...

But what really bugs me is that for some properties one sees when `get(get(gca, 'children'))` there are several fixed possible values, but they are not documented anywhere.

Now in MATLAB, I guess, just typing `set(handle, 'property')` without providing a value should evoke an error message followed by a set of all possible values. But unfortunately in octave, error messages usually are a little bit less helpful. So I searched the WHOLE web! I guess. Does anyone have an idea on how to display those possible feats I'm currently missing out on because I simply don't know 'em?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, do you mean you want a list of axes properties? In that case [see this section of the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Axes-Properties.html#Axes-Properties).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a list of read only property names for a plot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13801873/get-a-list-of-read-only-property-names-for-a-plot). Using the solution to this answer, you should be able to obtain the list of names of the settable and non-settable properties of an object.

Comment: @Thor: The link tells me, that for example the property "zdir" has the options 'Either "forward" or "reverse".' But there are a lot of properties on the page, that are not commented, like "alimmode", which in my plot is set to "auto". I found that out, typing get(gca, 'alimmode'); But what (except for the obvious "manual" in this case) other values can i _set_ for "alimmode"? @ Eitan: I already know the get/set-commands. Should i reformulate the question?

Comment: @Eitan: The problem is that, contrary to matlab, octave returns an error, when 'set' is called with a handler (and a property) but without an argument. "error: line::defaults: not implemented"

Comment: @ps_st: it seems the documentation is lacking, you can get some sense of it by looking at [the source](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/8d32a887754a/libinterp/interpfcn/graphics.in.h#l3759), alimmode alternatives are defined around line 3759.

Comment: @ps_st if the list of possible values is missing on the documentation (it's not on the help nor or on the manual), that's a bug. Please [report it](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=additem&group=octave).

Comment: `Now in MATLAB, I guess, just typing set(handle, 'property') without providing a value should evoke an error message followed by a set of all possible values.` there is no error message if you do not provide any value, just a cell array of all possible values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Octave you can get all possible property names using this command `get (0, "factory")` which returns factory values stored in the root figure object, see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Managing-Default-Properties.html) for details. For example, you can take `factoryaxesxgrid` and`factoryaxesygrid` properties and then use names `defaultaxesxgrid` and `defaultaxesygrid` correspondingly (replacing "factory" with "default") and run commands `set(0, 'defaultaxesxgrid', on);` and `set(0, 'defaultaxesygrid', on);` to make major grid appear by default.